# Panda dataframe - count how many times the number got repeated in one csv based on condition's from another csv

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv

I have 2 csv files-

CSV 1 :

```
    Date-Time            Code     MSG           ID
 2023/06/20 16:10:34     104     PKTS_DELIVERY  129
 2023/06/20 16:10:56     104     PKTS_SENT      132
 2023/06/20 16:11:56     104     PKTS_SENT      132
 2023/06/20 16:12:37     104     PKTS_SENT      132 <-- Ignore coz STATUS != 'Pending'
 2023/06/20 16:13:07     104     PKTS_PENDING   129
 2023/06/20 16:13:26     104     PKTS_PENDING   132 <-- Ignore coz STATUS != 'Pending'
 2023/06/20 16:14:17     104     PKTS_SENT      132
 2023/06/20 16:15:17     104     PKTS_SENT      132
 2023/06/20 16:15:34     104     PKTS_SENT      132
 2023/06/20 16:16:58     104     PKTS_SENT      140
 2023/06/20 16:17:17     104     PKTS_SENT      156
 2023/06/20 16:18:20     104     PKTS_SENT      129
 2023/06/20 16:19:22     104     PKTS_PENDING   180
```

CSV 2 -

```
   Date-Time             Pkt        MSG      STATUS
 2023/06/20 16:10:21     101     PKT_STATUS  Delivery 
 2023/06/20 16:10:31     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending 
 2023/06/20 16:10:41     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending 
 2023/06/20 16:10:51     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending <-- Count-1
 2023/06/20 16:11:01     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending 
 2023/06/20 16:11:11     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending 
 2023/06/20 16:11:21     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending 
 2023/06/20 16:11:31     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending 
 2023/06/20 16:11:41     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending 
 2023/06/20 16:11:51     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending <-- Count-2
 2023/06/20 16:12:01     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending 
 2023/06/20 16:12:11     101     PKT_STATUS  Staff 
 2023/06/20 16:12:36     101     PKT_STATUS  Staff 
 2023/06/20 16:12:56     101     PKT_STATUS  Staff 
 2023/06/20 16:13:30     101     PKT_STATUS  Staff 
 2023/06/20 16:14:19     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending <-- Count-1
 2023/06/20 16:15:15     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending <-- Count-2
 2023/06/20 16:15:40     101     PKT_STATUS  Pending <-- Count-3
```

I am trying to find the number of count's i.e. how many times **ID=132** repeated after
**ID-129** from CSV-1, if and only if **'STATUS' = 'Pending'** from CSV-2 and nearest time-delta within 10 seconds.

Output-

```
    Date/Time            Code       MSG         ID     Count
 2023/06/20 16:10:34     104     PKTS_DELIVERY  129     2
 2023/06/20 16:13:07     104     PKTS_PENDING   132     3
```